# Can I use the Windows 7 Start Menu search box to search files on a server?

Tags: windows-7, search, start-menu

I store most of my documents on a file server, and I'd like the Windows 7 Start Menu search box to search them.  I don't want them to be available offline -- I've got more space on the server than on my PC, so there's not enough room, and the LAN connection is fast enough that there's no need anyway.  Is it possible to just add a UNC path to the locations that are searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always manually search the server volume from explorer.  However, searching from the Start Menu only searches locations that are Indexed.  Search the start menu for "Indexing Options" to bring up the dialog box that will show you what is currently configured.

Unfortunately, Windows won't let you add a network volume to the list of locations to be indexed.  You need the server hosting the file share to be running one of the Windows indexing services (depending on the server's OS version) which your client will then use while connected.  If the server is just a NAS, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Need to run the 'Windows Search Service' in 2008 R2 (not Windows Indexing Service which is legacy/2003)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.